# tcpdump error "WARNING: can't get TPACKET_V2 header len on packet socket: Operation not supported"

Tags: docker, apple-m1, tcpdump, apple-silicon

I run docker on apple m1, in an ubuntu environment, install tcp-dump through apt-get, but tcpdump runs with an error:

`tcpdump: WARNING: can't get TPACKET_V2 header len on packet socket: Operation not supported Warning: Kernel filter failed: Bad file descriptor tcpdump: can't remove kernel filter: Protocol not available`

[image]

my docker image is arm platform:
https://hub.docker.com/layers/200959275/xushengbin/ubuntu-networking/master/images/sha256-2d1fde055c779978b0cace24ed0796f8669e536ce252366ba210cafe5149a7bb?context=repo

I want to know, under arm architecture, will there be any difference in running docker?

Comment: and my Dockerfile is https://github.com/albin504/ubuntu-networking/blob/master/Dockerfile